# Twitter4J throws exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

unable to get twitter instance, please suggest which I have done mistake

**Code :**

```
String consumerKey = "************************";

    //Your Twitter App's Consumer Secret
    String consumerSecret = "********************";

    //Your Twitter Access Token
    String accessToken = "**********************************";

    //Your Twitter Access Token Secret
    String accessTokenSecret = "*****************************";

    //Instantiate a re-usable and thread-safe factory
    TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory();

    //Instantiate a new Twitter instance
    Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance(); /// **problem comes over here**

    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret));
```

**while migrating from twitter v1 to v1.1**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterFactory.getInstance(Ltwitter4j/auth/AccessToken;)Ltwitter4j/Twitter;
>       at com.verve.meetin.twitter.twitterAuthenticationServlet.doGet(twitterAuthenticationServlet.java:151)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   INFO-Inside user upcoming trips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code with the latest released version (3.0.3) and it compiled, and ran fine.

I think that you may have two different versions of Twitter4J on the class path, or that you are compiling with one version and running with another. One version will have the method and the other won't.

Note that [`TwitterFactory#getInstance(AccessToken)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterFactory.html#getInstance%28twitter4j.auth.AccessToken%29), which is the missing method that the exception is reporting, was introduced in version 2.1.9 onwards.